# Is it neccessary for me to update my kernel? And how?

Tags: kernel, upgrade, kubuntu

I'm trying to install Kubuntu on a VM in order to do some deep learning following this guide: 
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-14.04-VirtualBox-VM

I'm stuck in the step of the guide that says "Install system updates (3.13.0-32 -> 3.13.0-36)". As far as I've understood this means that I should update the kernel of the OS. However, when I search Google for how to do this I find many different ways to do it (https://www.google.dk/search?q=kubuntu+update+kernel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=lhakVLShMIrMygOciIHICA). None of them seem very easy and I can't seem to figure out how to get exactly version 3.13.0-36.

What is the easiest way to update the kernel, and is it even necessary to update the kernel in order for the installation to work?

Comment: You should describe what exactly your problem is. I.e. what are you supposed to do and what don't you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not necessary but, If you want to be up to date then do them..

or else type on command line

apt-get update

apt-get upgrade

it will update your repository  and upgrade the needed packages automatically.

Comment: And the kernel is part of the packages and not something separate?

Comment: kernel is saparate then all packages... packages are the upper layer of kernel..   kernel is something which make you to communicate with hardwares.. so it is middleware.. and packages(inspite of kernel) are the one which updates your programs over your kernel.